# Как правильно настроить маршрутизацию при авторизации пользователя

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc

У меня на главной стр. 2-е ссылки:

- 1-ая для обычных пользователей
- 2-ая для администратора

для этих страниц у меня 3 контроллера:

1-ый для страницы пользователя - `FriendsController`

```
[Authorize(Roles = "admin, user")]
public class FriendsController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<FriendsController> _logger;
    private readonly Db_usersContext _context;

    public FriendsController(Db_usersContext context, ILogger<FriendsController> logger)
    {
        _context = context;
        _logger = logger;
    }

            
    // GET: Friends
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string nothing)
    {
        string userName;
        // userName=(string)TempData["userName"];
        userName = User.Identity.Name;
        
        var db_usersContext = _context.Friend.Include(f => f.City).Include(f => f.District).Include(f => f.FieldActivity).Include(f => f.PollingStation).Include(f => f.User).
                                Where(f => f.User.UserName.Equals(userName)); 
        return View(await db_usersContext.ToListAsync());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index([Bind("UserName", "Password", "ReturnUrl")] LoginModel loginViewModel)
    {
        string userName = loginViewModel.UserName;

        var db_usersContext = _context.Friend.Include(f => f.City).Include(f => f.District).Include(f => f.FieldActivity).Include(f => f.PollingStation).Include(f => f.User).
                                Where(f => f.User.UserName.Equals(userName));
        return View(await db_usersContext.ToListAsync());
    }


    // GET: Friends/Create
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewData["CityId"] = new SelectList(_context.City, "IdCity", "Name");
        ViewData["DistrictId"] = new SelectList(_context.District, "IdDistrict", "Name");
        ViewData["FieldActivityId"] = new SelectList(_context.Fieldactivity, "IdFieldActivity", "Name");
        ViewData["PollingStationId"] = new SelectList(_context.PollingStation, "IdPollingStation", "Name");
        ViewData["UserId"] = new SelectList(_context.User, "IdUser", "UserName");
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Friends/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("IdFriend,FamilyName,Name,PatronymicName,DateBirth,CityId,Street,House,Apartment,Telephone,DistrictId,PollingStationId,Organization,FieldActivityId,PhoneNumberResponsible,DateRegistrationSite,VotingDate,Description,UserId")] Friend friend)
    {
        List<Friend> searchFriend = _context.Friend.Where(frnd => frnd.Name.Equals(friend.Name) & frnd.FamilyName.Equals(friend.FamilyName) & frnd.PatronymicName.Equals(friend.PatronymicName) & frnd.DateBirth.Value.Date == friend.DateBirth.Value.Date).ToList();

        if (searchFriend.Count==0)
        {
           
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                long idUserSave = _context.User.Where(u => u.UserName.Equals(User.Identity.Name)).FirstOrDefault().IdUser;
                friend.UserId = idUserSave;

                _context.Add(friend);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            ViewData["CityId"] = new SelectList(_context.City, "IdCity", "Name", friend.CityId);
            ViewData["DistrictId"] = new SelectList(_context.District, "IdDistrict", "Name", friend.DistrictId);
            ViewData["FieldActivityId"] = new SelectList(_context.Fieldactivity, "IdFieldActivity", "Name", friend.FieldActivityId);
            ViewData["PollingStationId"] = new SelectList(_context.PollingStation, "IdPollingStation", "Name", friend.PollingStationId);
            ViewData["UserId"] = new SelectList(_context.User, "IdUser", "UserName", friend.UserId);
            return View(friend);
        }
        else return Content("Данный пользователь уже был внесен в списки ранее!");
    }

    // GET: Friends/Edit/5
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(long? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var friend = await _context.Friend.FindAsync(id);
        if (friend == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        ViewData["CityId"] = new SelectList(_context.City, "IdCity", "Name", friend.CityId);
        ViewData["DistrictId"] = new SelectList(_context.District, "IdDistrict", "Name", friend.DistrictId);
        ViewData["FieldActivityId"] = new SelectList(_context.Fieldactivity, "IdFieldActivity", "Name", friend.FieldActivityId);
        ViewData["PollingStationId"] = new SelectList(_context.PollingStation, "IdPollingStation", "Name", friend.PollingStationId);
        ViewData["UserId"] = new SelectList(_context.User, "IdUser", "UserName", friend.UserId);
        return View(friend);
    }

    // POST: Friends/Edit/5
    // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(long id, [Bind("IdFriend,FamilyName,Name,PatronymicName,DateBirth,CityId,Street,House,Apartment,Telephone,DistrictId,PollingStationId,Organization,FieldActivityId,PhoneNumberResponsible,DateRegistrationSite,VotingDate,Description,UserId")] Friend friend)
    {

        if (id != friend.IdFriend)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        List<Friend> searchFriend = _context.Friend.Where(frnd => frnd.Name.Equals(friend.Name) & frnd.FamilyName.Equals(friend.FamilyName) & frnd.PatronymicName.Equals(friend.PatronymicName) & frnd.DateBirth.Value.Date == friend.DateBirth.Value.Date & frnd.IdFriend!=friend.IdFriend).ToList();

        if (searchFriend.Count == 0)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                long idUserSave = _context.User.Where(u => u.UserName.Equals(User.Identity.Name)).FirstOrDefault().IdUser;
                friend.UserId = idUserSave;

                try
                {
                    _context.Update(friend);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                {
                    if (!FriendExists(friend.IdFriend))
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            ViewData["CityId"] = new SelectList(_context.City, "IdCity", "Name", friend.CityId);
            ViewData["DistrictId"] = new SelectList(_context.District, "IdDistrict", "Name", friend.DistrictId);
            ViewData["FieldActivityId"] = new SelectList(_context.Fieldactivity, "IdFieldActivity", "Name", friend.FieldActivityId);
            ViewData["PollingStationId"] = new SelectList(_context.PollingStation, "IdPollingStation", "Name", friend.PollingStationId);
            ViewData["UserId"] = new SelectList(_context.User, "IdUser", "UserName", friend.UserId);
            return View(friend);
        }
        else return Content("Данный пользователь уже присутствует в списках!");
    }

    // GET: Friends/Delete/5
    public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(long? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var friend = await _context.Friend
            .Include(f => f.City)
            .Include(f => f.District)
            .Include(f => f.FieldActivity)
            .Include(f => f.PollingStation)
            .Include(f => f.User)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.IdFriend == id);
        if (friend == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(friend);
    }

    // POST: Friends/Delete/5
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(long id)
    {
        var friend = await _context.Friend.FindAsync(id);
        _context.Friend.Remove(friend);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }

    private bool FriendExists(long id)
    {
        return _context.Friend.Any(e => e.IdFriend == id);
    }

    //public IActionResult LogOff()
    //{
    //    HttpContext.SignOutAsync("Cookie");
    //    return Redirect("/Home/Index");
    //}
}
```

2-ой для страницы администратора - `AdminController`

```
[Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
public class AdminController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<AdminController> _logger;
    private readonly Db_usersContext _context;

    public AdminController(Db_usersContext context, ILogger<AdminController> logger)
    {
        _context = context;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        string roleUser = User.FindFirst(x => x.Type == ClaimsIdentity.DefaultRoleClaimType).Value;
        var db_usersContext = _context.Friend.Include(f => f.City).Include(f => f.District).Include(f => f.FieldActivity).Include(f => f.PollingStation).Include(f => f.User);
        return View(await db_usersContext.ToListAsync());
    }


    // GET: Friends/Create
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewData["CityId"] = new SelectList(_context.City, "IdCity", "Name");
        ViewData["DistrictId"] = new SelectList(_context.District, "IdDistrict", "Name");
        ViewData["FieldActivityId"] = new SelectList(_context.Fieldactivity, "IdFieldActivity", "Name");
        ViewData["PollingStationId"] = new SelectList(_context.PollingStation, "IdPollingStation", "Name");
        ViewData["UserId"] = new SelectList(_context.User, "IdUser", "UserName");
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Friends/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("IdFriend,FamilyName,Name,PatronymicName,DateBirth,CityId,Street,House,Apartment,Telephone,DistrictId,PollingStationId,Organization,FieldActivityId,PhoneNumberResponsible,DateRegistrationSite,VotingDate,Description,UserId")] Friend friend)
    {
        List<Friend> searchFriend = _context.Friend.Where(frnd => frnd.Name.Equals(friend.Name) & frnd.FamilyName.Equals(friend.FamilyName) & frnd.PatronymicName.Equals(friend.PatronymicName) & frnd.DateBirth.Value.Date == friend.DateBirth.Value.Date).ToList();

        if (searchFriend.Count == 0)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                long idUserSave = _context.User.Where(u => u.UserName.Equals(User.Identity.Name)).FirstOrDefault().IdUser;
                friend.UserId = idUserSave;

                _context.Add(friend);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            ViewData["CityId"] = new SelectList(_context.City, "IdCity", "Name", friend.CityId);
            ViewData["DistrictId"] = new SelectList(_context.District, "IdDistrict", "Name", friend.DistrictId);
            ViewData["FieldActivityId"] = new SelectList(_context.Fieldactivity, "IdFieldActivity", "Name", friend.FieldActivityId);
            ViewData["PollingStationId"] = new SelectList(_context.PollingStation, "IdPollingStation", "Name", friend.PollingStationId);
            ViewData["UserId"] = new SelectList(_context.User, "IdUser", "UserName", friend.UserId);
            return View(friend);
        }
        else return Content("Данный пользователь уже был внесен в списки ранее");
    }

    // GET: Friends/Edit/5
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(long? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var friend = await _context.Friend.FindAsync(id);
        if (friend == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        ViewData["CityId"] = new SelectList(_context.City, "IdCity", "Name", friend.CityId);
        ViewData["DistrictId"] = new SelectList(_context.District, "IdDistrict", "Name", friend.DistrictId);
        ViewData["FieldActivityId"] = new SelectList(_context.Fieldactivity, "IdFieldActivity", "Name", friend.FieldActivityId);
        ViewData["PollingStationId"] = new SelectList(_context.PollingStation, "IdPollingStation", "Name", friend.PollingStationId);
        ViewData["UserId"] = new SelectList(_context.User, "IdUser", "UserName", friend.UserId);
        return View(friend);
    }

    // POST: Friends/Edit/5
    // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(long id, [Bind("IdFriend,FamilyName,Name,PatronymicName,DateBirth,CityId,Street,House,Apartment,Telephone,DistrictId,PollingStationId,Organization,FieldActivityId,PhoneNumberResponsible,DateRegistrationSite,VotingDate,Description,UserId")] Friend friend)
    {

        if (id != friend.IdFriend)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                _context.Update(friend);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!FriendExists(friend.IdFriend))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        ViewData["CityId"] = new SelectList(_context.City, "IdCity", "Name", friend.CityId);
        ViewData["DistrictId"] = new SelectList(_context.District, "IdDistrict", "Name", friend.DistrictId);
        ViewData["FieldActivityId"] = new SelectList(_context.Fieldactivity, "IdFieldActivity", "Name", friend.FieldActivityId);
        ViewData["PollingStationId"] = new SelectList(_context.PollingStation, "IdPollingStation", "Name", friend.PollingStationId);
        ViewData["UserId"] = new SelectList(_context.User, "IdUser", "UserName", friend.UserId);
        return View(friend);
    }

    // GET: Friends/Delete/5
    public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(long? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var friend = await _context.Friend
            .Include(f => f.City)
            .Include(f => f.District)
            .Include(f => f.FieldActivity)
            .Include(f => f.PollingStation)
            .Include(f => f.User)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.IdFriend == id);
        if (friend == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(friend);
    }

    // POST: Friends/Delete/5
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(long id)
    {
        var friend = await _context.Friend.FindAsync(id);
        _context.Friend.Remove(friend);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }

    private bool FriendExists(long id)
    {
        return _context.Friend.Any(e => e.IdFriend == id);
    }

    [Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
    public IActionResult About()
    {
        return Content("Вход только для администратора");
    }
    //public IActionResult LogOff()
    //{
    //    HttpContext.SignOutAsync("Cookie");
    //    return Redirect("/Home/Index");
    //}

}
```

3-ий - контроллер для авторизации и регистрации - `AccountController`, содержащий:

- метод `Login` GET
- метод `Login` POST - перенаправляет после успешной авторизации
- метод `Register` GET
- метод `Register` POST

.

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private  Db_usersContext db_context;
    public AccountController(Db_usersContext context)
    {
        db_context = context;
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            User user = await db_context.User
                .Include(u => u.Role)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.UserName == model.UserName && u.Password == model.Password);
            if (user != null)
            {
                await Authenticate(user); // аутентификация

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Friends");
            }
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Некорректные логин и(или) пароль");
        }
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Register()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            User user = await db_context.User.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.UserName == model.UserName);
            if (user == null)
            {
                // добавляем пользователя в бд
                user = new User { UserName = model.UserName, Password = model.Password, Name=model.Name, FamilyName=model.FamilyName, Telephone=model.Telephone };
                //При регистрации пользователю будет присваиваться роль "user", которая, как ожидается,
                //добавляется в базу данных с помощью инициализации в классе Startup.
                Role userRole = await db_context.Role.FirstOrDefaultAsync(r => r.Name == "user");
                if (userRole != null)
                    user.Role = userRole;

                db_context.User.Add(user);
                await db_context.SaveChangesAsync();

                await Authenticate(user); // аутентификация

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Friends");
            }
            else
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Некорректные логин и(или) пароль");
        }
        return View(model);
    }

    private async Task Authenticate(User user)
    {
        
        var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(ClaimsIdentity.DefaultNameClaimType, user.UserName),
            // Усанавливается роль, которой обладает пользователь
            // Для указания роли здесь применяется тип claim ClaimsIdentity.DefaultRoleClaimType
            new Claim(ClaimsIdentity.DefaultRoleClaimType, user.Role?.Name)
        };
        // создаем объект ClaimsIdentity
        //С помощью объекта ClaimsIdentity, который возвращается свойством User.Identity,
        //мы можем управлять объектами claim у текущего пользователя
        ClaimsIdentity id = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "ApplicationCookie", ClaimsIdentity.DefaultNameClaimType,
            ClaimsIdentity.DefaultRoleClaimType);
        // установка аутентификационных куки
        //app.UseCookieAuthentication - схема аутентификации, которая была использована при установки middleware app.UseCookieAuthentication в классе Startup
        // в качестве второго параметра передается объект ClaimsPrincipal, который представляет пользователя
        await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(id));
        //И после вызова метода расширения HttpContext.SignInAsync в ответ клиенту будут отправляться аутентификационные куки,
        //которые при последующих запросах будут передаваться обратно на сервер, десериализоваться и использоваться для аутентификации пользователя.
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
    {
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
    }
}
```

Из контроллера `AccountController` метода `Login` POST меня может перенаправить только на 1-у станицу сейчас это страница пользователя.
Страница авторизации:

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6"></div>      
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <span class="heading" style="align-items:center">АВТОРИЗАЦИЯ</span>
        <form class="form-horizontal" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Login" method="post">
            <input hidden asp-for="ReturnUrl" type="text" value="" />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">Имя пользователя</label>
                <input asp-for="UserName" class="form-control" type="email" id="inputEmail" placeholder="E-mail" />
                <span asp-validation-for="UserName"></span>
                <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">Пароль</label>
                <input asp-for="Password" class="form-control" type="password" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Password"></span>
                <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
                <a href="#" class="fa fa-question-circle"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Войти" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-action="Register" asp-controller="Account">
                        <font size="2" color="blue" face="Arial">Зарегистрироваться</font>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
</div>
```

Мне нужно чтобы, если выбирали ссылку страницы администратора, то перенаправляло не на страницу пользователя, а на страницу администратора.

Как это правильно сделать?
Определить в `AdminController` отдельно методы `Login` GET и `Login` POST для авторизации на эту страницу и перенаправлять при клике на неё в эти методы? Вроде такой себе костыль.

Есть более верный метод?

Comment: Проиллюстрируйте пожалуйста вопрос частями кода, вставляйте код текстом. Так будет легче понять, о чем речь.

Comment: @aepot, дополнил

Comment: не понял вашу проблему, но если она про перенаправление после авторизации, то для этого и есть параметр returnUrl

Comment: @tym32167, но станица для авторизации одна для всех  и мы на ней можем прописать только 1-н url в параметре, который потом вернем в post запросе

Comment: вы можете прописать там любой URL который вам понравится, это же ваш код. Прописывайте для вдмина и юзера там разные URL и все дела

Comment: @tym32167,  ну например я пропишу на этой странице авторизации два скрытых поля с 2-мя url (<input hidden asp-for="ReturnUrl" type="text" value="" />), как контроллеру авторизации дать знать какой url он должен использовать?

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо на форме авторизации добавить:

```
asp-route-returnUrl="@Model.ReturnUrl"
```

это будет передавать url в модель авторизации, по которому кликнул пользователь.

В POST-контроллере авторизации необходимо прописать проверку на наличие url:

```
if (user != null)
            {
                await Authenticate(user); // аутентификация

                // проверяем, принадлежит ли URL приложению
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.ReturnUrl) && Url.IsLocalUrl(model.ReturnUrl))
                {
                    return Redirect(model.ReturnUrl);
                }
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Friends");
                }
            }
```